# AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'ndata'

Tags: python, database, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook, pytorch

I'm fairly new to Deep Learning and I'm trying to combine vq-vae models with GCN using import DGL

I use Google Collab. I checked which packages I had installed in my base environment and troch and dgl were up to date. Everything went fine until I fit my model, that's when I got an attribute error that I wrote as the title of the post

Here is my code:

```
class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_hiddens, num_residual_layers, num_residual_hiddens, 
                 num_embeddings, embedding_dim, commitment_cost, decay=0):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        
        self._encoder = Encoder(3, num_hiddens,
                                num_residual_layers, 
                                num_residual_hiddens)
        self._pre_vq_conv = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=num_hiddens, 
                                      out_channels=embedding_dim,
                                      kernel_size=1, 
                                      stride=1)
        if decay > 0.0:
            self._vq_vae = VectorQuantizerEMA(num_embeddings, embedding_dim, 
                                              commitment_cost, decay)
        else:
            self._vq_vae = VectorQuantizer(num_embeddings, embedding_dim,
                                           commitment_cost)
        self._decoder = Decoder(embedding_dim,
                                num_hiddens, 
                                num_residual_layers, 
                                num_residual_hiddens)

    def forward(self, g):
        x = g.ndata['feat']
        z = self._encoder(x)
        z = self._pre_vq_conv(z)
        loss, quantized, perplexity, _ = self._vq_vae(z)
        x_recon = self._decoder(quantized)

        return loss, x_recon, perplexity



model = Model(num_hiddens, num_residual_layers, num_residual_hiddens,
              num_embeddings, embedding_dim, 
              commitment_cost, decay).to(device)

optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate, amsgrad=False)
```

with last program is error

```
model.train()
train_res_recon_error = []
train_res_perplexity = []

for i, batch in enumerate(training_loader):
    batch_graph = batch.to(device)  # Memindahkan graf ke perangkat yang sesuai
    optimizer.zero_grad()

    

for batch_graph in training_loader:
    batch_graph = batch_graph.to(device)
    inputs = batch_graph.ndata['feat']
    batch_size = inputs.shape[0]
    # Memastikan dimensi input sesuai dengan kebutuhan model
    inputs = inputs.reshape(batch_size, -1, 1, 1)

    optimizer.zero_grad()
    vq_loss, data_recon, perplexity = model(inputs)
    recon_error = F.mse_loss(data_recon, inputs) / data_variance
    loss = recon_error + vq_loss
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()


    # Menjalankan model pada data input
    inputs = batch_graph.ndata['feat'].to(device)
    vq_loss, data_recon, perplexity = model(inputs)

    # Menghitung error rekonstruksi
    recon_error = F.mse_loss(data_recon, inputs) / data_variance

    # Menghitung total loss
    loss = recon_error + vq_loss

    # Backward pass dan update parameter
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()


    #optimizer.step()

    train_res_recon_error.append(recon_error.item())
    train_res_perplexity.append(perplexity.item())

    if (i+1) % 100 == 0:
        print('%d iterations' % (i+1))
        print('recon_error: %.3f' % np.mean(train_res_recon_error[-100:]))
        print('perplexity: %.3f' % np.mean(train_res_perplexity[-100:]))
        print()
```

And the error is

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-80-717a0674743f> in <cell line: 14>()
     20 
     21     optimizer.zero_grad()
---> 22     vq_loss, data_recon, perplexity = model(inputs)
     23     recon_error = F.mse_loss(data_recon, inputs) / data_variance
     24     loss = recon_error + vq_loss

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1499                 or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1500                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1501             return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1502         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1503         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

<ipython-input-75-1fbfd62ffc59> in forward(self, g)
     23 
     24     def forward(self, g):
---> 25         x = g.ndata['feat']
     26         z = self._encoder(x)
     27         z = self._pre_vq_conv(z)

AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'ndata'
```

Answer (score 0):

The model expects a whole graph batch_graph as input whichh has an attribute `ndata`. You instead first extract `ndata` from the batch graph, and the resulting tensor does not itself have an attribute `ndata` hence the `AttributeError`.

Comment: Give us an example of the program's source code to fix the problem

Comment: I don't know enough about the code to do that. I do not have access to the dataset so I don't know the actual structure of your data. It is quite evident what your problem is without this; try passing `batch_graph` as the input directly rather than first accessing its attribute `ndata["feat"]`

Comment: dataset code is
transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (1.0, 1.0, 1.0))
])

training_data = datasets.MNIST(root="data", train=True, download=True, transform=transform)
validation_data = datasets.MNIST(root="data", train=False, download=True, transform=transform)
data_variance = np.var(training_data.data / 255.0)

def dgl_collate_fn(batch):
    graphs = [item for item in batch]
    return dgl.batch(graphs)

Comment: def convert_to_dgl_graph(data):
    graph_list = []
    for i in range(data.shape[0]):
        num_nodes = data.shape[1]
        graph = dgl.DGLGraph()
        graph.add_nodes(num_nodes)
        src, dst = torch.nonzero(data[i]).T
        graph.add_edges(src, dst)
        graph.ndata['feat'] = data[i].unsqueeze(1).float()[:, :num_nodes]
        graph_list.append(graph)
    return graph_list
training_graphs = convert_to_dgl_graph(training_data.data)
validation_graphs = convert_to_dgl_graph(validation_data.data)

Comment: training_loader = DataLoader(training_graphs, 
                             batch_size=batch_size, 
                             shuffle=True,
                             pin_memory=True, collate_fn=dgl_collate_fn)
validation_loader = DataLoader(validation_graphs,
                               batch_size=64,
                               shuffle=True,
                               pin_memory=True, collate_fn=dgl_collate_fn)